# Grid Margin from Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, margin

I have a wpf Application where's two grid inside one single grid like this

```
<window ....>
  <grid x:name="main_grid">
    <grid x:name="panel1">
        //...some stuff//
    </grid>
    <grid x:name="panel2">
        //...some stuff//
    </grid>
  </grid>
</window>
```

the main_grid is positioned to fit the whole window
I want to position Panel1 and Panel2 margin left and top to 0 from code behind.

what I tried is like this,

```
private void window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   int left = Convert.ToInt16(main_grid.Margin.Left);
   int top = Convert.ToInt16(main_grid.Margin.Top);
   panel1.margin = new Thickness(left, top, 0, 0);
   panel2.margin = new Thickness(left, top, 0, 0);
}
```

However, it's not working. figures...
Anybody have any solutions? please...

Comment: There are so many things wrong here. First you are setting the same margin to both panels so both would on top of each other (assuming the panels have the same horizontal and vertical orientation). And then the margin property is wrong Thickness takes (left,top,right,bottom);

Comment: why do it in codebehind? best to put UI code in UI (xaml) and just use the designer to design the layout and manually modified it to suit your need

Comment: this is of course not working. Where you defined the `o`? or it should be zero? Also note that the order of 4 arguments passed in `Thickness` is for `left, top, right, bottom`.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake about the margin. It's Ok in the original code, I just did the mistake here. and the o is 0. And I need those 2 panel over each other, so it doesn't mater. anyway, my window is set to change it's height and width property to PrimaryScreenHeight and Width, so I don't know that screen height/width the user will have. that's why I wanto to do it in code behind so that the margin can be at 0

Answer (score 2):

Why not in XAML like this:

```
<Grid x:name="main_grid"
      Margin="10,20,30,40">
    <Grid x:name="panel1"
          Margin="10,20,30,40">
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:name="panel2"
          Margin="10,20,30,40">
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```